# Mali gpu directory

Tags: android, arm, gpu, processor, mali

I cannot find the gpu directory for Mali Gpu's current frequency in the root flile system.

Like in case of Qualcomm Adreno GPU the path for the gpu frequency is /sys/devices/platform/kgsl-3d0.0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpuclk.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the silicon provider, so it's not a standard location (if it exists at all).

Comment: Ooh I see is there any workarround

Comment: Just have to find chipmaker for the phone(s) in question and search each one specifically for its answer unfortunately, no easy workaround. There are answers for various phones on various forums.

Comment: @ShubhamChakraborty have you found it?

Comment: No I'm not able to find any workaround except that if the kernel exposes the gpu related files  in  /sys/kernel/gpu  is the only workaround and the only way to read from the files is to root the device.